# Can I route an external website using python flask?

Tags: python, url, flask, routes, external

I'm really new to Python Flask and I'm using it for a web app that shows information on football teams in Scotland.

There're no problems with the first part of code, that I know of. It works, but this is for a local page. The one below is the one I'm having a problem with, I want to use routing so the user can type in the address bar the football team they wish to see information about. By typing in `localhost:5000/teams/aberdeen/` and for it to goto `http://spfl.co.uk/clubs/aberdeen/`
Is this possible?

```
@app.route('/media')
def media():
  return render_template('media.html'), 200 

@app.route('/teams/aberdeen')
def celtic():
    return redirect("http://spfl.co.uk/clubs/aberdeen/", code=302)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your route to take a parameter you can put it between `<` and `>`, as noted in the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#url-route-registrations).

> Variable parts in the route can be specified with angular brackets (`/user/<username>`).

So the `celtic` function becomes:

```
@app.route('/teams/<teamname>')
def celtic(teamname):
    return redirect("http://spfl.co.uk/clubs/%s/" % teamname, code=302)
```